# Azure Pipepline with task Sonarqube https

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I added a Sonarqube task into my azure build pipeline, in order to login to my sonarqube server I need to run a command, which uses trunst store ssl.

my pipeline looks just like this:

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: abc-sonarqube
    scannerMode: CLI
    configMode: manual
    cliProjectKey: 'abc'
    cliProjectName: 'abc'
    cliSources: src
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.build.abcdef.com
      sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mvn/sonar.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I am not sure, if this command "sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mvn/sonar.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" correct is.

I got the error "API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"}
"

PS: my project is angular project.

any solutions?

Comment: Hi, does the info mentioned in Leo's answer could help you solve the issue? Did you still facing any other error now? You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it is help. Or kindly to leave comment below if still meeting errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Pipepline with task Sonarqube https

This issue should be related in how the configure task works. So, even if we add the certificate to the java trustore, the task that sets the configuration uses a different runtime (not java at least) to communicate with the server, that’s why you still get that certificate error.

To resolve this issue, you could try to:

> set a global variable, NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS, and set it to a copy of
>   the root cert we had stored locally in a directory. See [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/1W8raF6ZMVM/iFgQhVENAAAJ).

Check the [related ticket](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/tfs-buid-server-cannot-connect-to-teh-sonarqube-server-over-ssl/1194/3) for some more details.

Hope this helps.